show ipv6 address on default Gateway

On above picture, IPv6 Default Gateway field is empty, why so?

you don't have a (routable) ipv6 address

If this is your home system, then you need to contact your ISP and ask for IPv6 address space then update your router accordingly. You may even have to replace the router if it does not support IPv6.


On above picture, IPv6 Default Gateway field is empty, why so?

The most likely reason why there is no Default Gateway configured is that your System Administrator did not configure a Default Gateway, or that your Network Administrator did not configure the necessary configuration services to automatically configure a Default Gateway.
Furthermore, the address is a link-local address, which means it is not allowed to be routed anyway. Even if there were a Default Gateway defined, the gateway is required by the standards to drop the packets and not route them.
If you want a routable IPv6 address, you need to ask your Network Administrator to provide you one, and either ask your System Administrator to configure the address for you or ask your Network Administrator to set up a configuration service such as NDP or DHCPv6,
